# Reading Matroska (MKV) metadata and extracting streams

Tags: c++, video

I am attempting to write a program in C++ that will need to display metadata from a MKV file and extract streams from the file.

I looked at libmatroska and found it difficult to use because it is very low level. There are also no examples on usage apart from mkvtoolnix making it difficult to use due to having to bring in most of mkvinfo and mkvextract. libmediainfo covers most of what I need although it would be nice to be more flexible if possible.

In addition, I have found no simple way of extracting the video stream without using mkvextract to write it to a temporary file.

Any advice would be appreciated

Comment: What info that you cannot find from mkvinfo that you have to write your own display program?

Comment: Nothing really. The purpose is to do something similar to what eac3to does.